# Treeview like representation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Lets say using the following data I would like to create a treeview-like representation.

```
var demoData = [
                {"name": "person1", "parent": ""},
                {"name": "person2", "parent": "person1"},
                {"name": "person3", "parent": "person1"},
                {"name": "person4", "parent": "person2"},
                {"name": "person5", "parent": "person3"}
                ];
```

The output should be something like this.

```
person1
|--person2
|  |--person4
|--person3
   |--person5
```

How would I do this with AngularJS. I know how to do this lets say in C# with a recursive function but cannot get my head around how to do this in AngularJS.

I have looked at other questions on SO but the data there was formatted in a different way so that the child entities were directly in the parent entity.

Comment: Quote "the child entities were directly in the parent entity." I guess that should be your target, reformat the data so you have it like this.

Comment: And if this would not be possible/out of my control?

Comment: Almost everything is possible, but for me it looks like that's the easiest way

Answer (score 0):

Generally (like in C#) you can achieve  recursive call by using `ng-include`.

One node calls `ng-include="'tree_item_renderer'` for each child.

Something like:

```
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer">
          <span>
            {{showNode(data)}}
          </span>
        <ul class="some" ng-show="data.show">       
           <li ng-repeat="data in data.nodes"
               ng-include="'tree_item_renderer'" tree-node></li>
        </ul>
</script>
```

And root call:

```
     <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in displayTree"
            ng-include="'tree_item_renderer'"></li>
      </ul>
```

The basic demo you can find here in <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EvjX6O?p=preview)**</kbd>

[image]